# Cannot resolve method setSupportActionbar()

Tags: java, android, activity

В коде появляются 2 ошибки:

```
Cannot resolve method setSupportActionbar

Cannot resolve method getSupportFragmentManager()
```

Импортировал `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar` но ничего не выходит. Вот код:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;


import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);**<<<<Ошибка здесь**
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());**<<<<Ошибка здесь**
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того, чтобы Вам был доступны методы `setSupportActionBar()` и `getSupportActionBar()`, вы должны наследоваться от `AppCompatActivity` или ее производных.

---

Просто измените строчку объявления класс на:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Все работает,Спасибо!!